# Как правильно записать формулу в паскаль?

Tags: pascal

Нужна помощь правильно записать такую формулу в паскаль? :) К примеру

```
b=(4*sqr(y)*exp(3*sin(v)))/3*exp(3*ln(z))+ln(x)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b := 4 * y * y * exp(3 * sin(v)) / (3 * z * z * z + ln(x));
```